# Facebook Marketing API - Creating an "advideo" in Sandbox Environment

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create a video in Sandbox mode but it throws me an output such as;

```
  Params:  {'title': 'test1', 'description': 'test'}
  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_x' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AL_IO0ED9eQLAYcVGH2Ae94"
      }
    }
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run;

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from pathlib import Path

my_app_id = 'xxxx'
my_app_secret = 'xxxx'
my_access_token = 'xxxx'

FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token, api_version="v14.0")
my_account = AdAccount('act_x')

video_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'video.mp4'

fields=[]
params = {
    "title" : "test1",
    "description": "test",
    "source": video_path
}
video = my_account.create_ad_video(params=params, fields=fields)
```

I'm wondering if im not able to create adimages or advideos in Sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I've mistakenly removed a character from act_id so it threw that error.

Be sure you have valid credentials, you can upload media in **Sandbox** mode.